# Why was my comment on this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

I was browsing through the active questions page today, and saw that Mooseman made an edit to [this answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/1704/165). He removed a link to an article an ebay. I figured it was due to our rule that we should avoid linking to product pages, but just because it's on ebay doesn't make it a product page, so I posted a comment asking @Mooseman to clarify his edit. However, my comment has since been deleted...

Text of comment:

> @Mooseman: Why did you remove the link to the Top 8 mittens and Gloves page? It's on ebay, but it's not a product page, it's an article. — Wipqozn 19 secs ago

Link to comment:

[How to keep your hands warm in winter while working on a laptop?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/how-to-keep-your-hands-warm-in-winter-while-working-on-a-laptop/1704#comment8851_1704)

Why was my comment deleted?

aka this comment: [How to keep your hands warm in winter while working on a laptop?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/how-to-keep-your-hands-warm-in-winter-while-working-on-a-laptop/1704#comment8851_1704)

EDIT: It looks like the link has since been added back in, which is good, but I still find it odd my comment was deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally deleted your comment under the reason "obsolete". The issue had been fixed within the five minute grace period.

I have restored your comment and left my own reply, stating that the I fixed the link.

**EDIT:** I've since removed *both* comments as they are obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

As is written in the [help for the comment privilege](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Comments are **temporary** "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

Comments are meant to be deleted if they are no longer relevant. When the action requested by your comment was performed, your comment became obsolete, and a moderator rightfully removed it as such.